# The submenu does not close when hovering over the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys i have two questions at once:

1. Why does not the submenu disappear when hovering over other links from the header
2. Why the submenu does not change when I hover over another link with a submenu ( The first time it works and then it doesn't change )

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <a href="" class="logo logo_position_header">
                <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="tines logo" class="logo__image" />
            </a>
            <div class="header__right">
                <nav class="header__nav">
                    <ul class="header__list">
                        <li class="header__item">
                            <a href="#" class="header__link">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header__item">
                            <a href="#" class="header__link">Use cases</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header__item">
                            <a href="#" class="header__link" data-opened-menu="1">Resources</a>
                            <nav class="header__submenu" data-opened="1">
                                <ul class="header__submenu-list">
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Webinars
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Get to know Tines and our use cases, live and on-demand.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Blog
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Read articles by team members, from company updates to tutorials.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Prodcast
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Listen to the latest episodes of our podcast, 'The Future of Security Operations.'</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Customers stories
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Learn how the world’s best security teams automate their work.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Story library
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Discover helpful example Stories, connect them to your own tools and start customizing instantly.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Video lessons
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Learn the basics of Tines one byte-sized video at a time.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Docs
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Get to know the features and concepts of Tines, in detail.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            API
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Browse the capabilities and endpoints of our comprehensive REST API.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header__item">
                            <a href="#" class="header__link" data-opened-menu="2">Company</a>
                            <nav class="header__submenu" data-opened="2">
                                <ul class="header__submenu-list">
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            About Tines
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Get to know our company and its mission.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Upcoming events
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Discover all upcoming events where you can meet the Tines team.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Careers
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">We’re hiring worldwide for a variety of jobs and roles.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Slack Community
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Chat with the Tines team and community of users on our Slack.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Customer love
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Hear what our customers have to say about Tines, in their own words.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Partnerships
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">Our technology alliances, product integrations, and channel partnerships.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Newsroom
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">See media coverage, download brand assets, or make a press inquiry.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="header__submenu-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="header__submenu-link">
                                            Gartner Cool Vendor
                                            <p class="header__submenu-description">We’re proud to be a 2021 Gartner Cool Vendor in Security Operations.</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header__item">
                            <a href="#" class="header__link">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <button class="btn btn__modal-open btn_color_purple" data-modal="1">Sign up for free</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
    background-color: var(--color-light);
    border-radius: 28px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header__submenu-list{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    background-color: var(--color-light);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 0 28px 28px;
}

.header__submenu-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: var(--color-dark);
    transition: color .2s linear;
}

.header__submenu-item{
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.header__submenu-description{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.25;
    opacity: .6;
    transition: opacity .1s;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.header__submenu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.header__show-submenu{
    border-radius: 28px 28px 0 0;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.header__right{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__nav{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
}

.header__list{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header__link{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: var(--color-dark);
    transition: color .2s linear;
    position: relative;
}

.header__link:hover{
    color: var(--color-main);
}

.header__item:not(:last-child){
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.header__item:last-child{
    margin: 0;
}

.header__inner{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__container{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: calc(100% - 24.2rem);
}
```

JS (The code certainly looks terrible, but I just started learning JS two days ago.  ):

```
let subResourcesLink = document.querySelector('.header__link[data-opened-menu="1"]'),
    subCompanyLink = document.querySelector('.header__link[data-opened-menu="2"]'),
    header = document.querySelector(".header"),
    subMenu = document.querySelector(".header__submenu"),
    headerLink = document.querySelector(".header__link");

subResourcesLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.add("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="1"]').classList.add("header__show-submenu");
});

subMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="1"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

header.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="1"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

headerLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="1"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

subCompanyLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.add("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="2"]').classList.add("header__show-submenu");
});

subMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="2"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

header.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="2"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

headerLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    document.querySelector(".header").classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
    document.querySelector('.header__submenu[data-opened="2"]').classList.remove("header__show-submenu");
});

subCompanyLink.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {});
```

Here's a link to the sandbox please take a look since I can't fully insert the code here https://codepen.io/Flain/pen/GRQdLMV

Comment: It seems like you are using the wrong element when triggering the mouseleave event. If you hover out of the white box completely, the menu disappears as expected.

Comment: have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp